# universal new line mode in csv reader make csv writer write mistake line break in file

Tags: python, csv

When i read csv file with universal line mode ("rU") cdv.reader it generates \r \n as new line in csv.writer. Do you know how to ignore new line in csv.writer? I had to use ("rU") in reader because my files contain new-line character.

this is the code i use

```
import csv

dict={}
with open('training_data.csv','rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,skipinitialspace=True)
for line in reader:
    try:
        dict[line[2]].append(line[3])
    except:
        dict[line[2]]=[line[3]]

with open('training_result.csv','w') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|',dialect='excel-tab')
for key in dict:
    writer.writerow([key,','.join(dict[key])])
```

The input is like this

```
username, some of tweet that
want to be processed
by machine , label
```

Because that is line break and universal line mode activated, when i catch the data and want to write with csv writer it would be the same

What i want to be the output is like this

```
username, some of tweet that want to be processed by machine , label
```

Should i remove all of line breaks in csv file? But it is too large, the csv is around 150MB and contain 700 thousand row. Is there any approaches for this?

I already play with reader properties such as skipinitialspace and dialect, but still cannot handle the problem

Comment: Do you always want to append line 2 to line 3?

Comment: Seems like it is not a valid csv file. can you share a pice of the csv file. So if that is the case you may try to identify  and force lines by using some identical values in the parse.

Comment: @BhargavRao Yes because i want to concatenate the tweet content(second column) based on label or username. That function is to catch many tweets for the same username. For instance username A have more than 2 tweets. Then i concatenate all of A tweets to implement "bag of words" analysis in the 2nd column. That's the idea :/

Comment: @LalithJayasinghe yeah i though so. I exported csv file from MongoDB (it was json file in MongoDB) by using 'mongoexport -d aipd -c ntb_datasift --csv -f "twitter.place.full_name","twitter.user.location","interaction.author.username","interaction.content","interaction.created_at","interaction.id" -o december_16_ntb_training_data.csv'

Comment: @LalithJayasinghe this is the example row in csv 

#header
twitter.place.full_name,twitter.user.location,interaction.author.username,interaction.content,interaction.created_at
#row_content
"Mataram, Kota Mataram",Mataram Nusa Tenggara Barat ,_adliahpartang,"Arti sahabat adalah
orang yang selalu ada atau selalu menemani hari-
hari kita baik itu dalam keadaanäó_ http://t.co/nIoZIlJPeh","Sat, 24 May 2014 06:39:09 +0000"

Comment: Can I have a part of real file sample? because new line characters are not available when you post ithere.

Comment: @LalithJayasinghe how can i send you sample file? I'm newbie here, thanks..

Comment: You have to upload the file to a public file server like Google drive or Dropbox , then paste the link here.

Comment: @LalithJayasinghe https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwYdCgNJv_fkNkJwODZadDVxVm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks. Please also create the expected result csv and send it too.

Comment: Is this the result you looking ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1xxO_DFKQ4AMnpRZGVvR0Q1VXM/view

Comment: Yes @LalithJayasinghe , thats it ! Do know how to encounter the problem? Or should i just use json file instead?

Comment: Side note: you want to read PEP 8 so as to follow everybody's space convention. More importantly even, you don't want to shadow the builtin `dict` by using the same name for one of your variables, this is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by replacing new lines by ", " and adding a new line for each new append. IF you do not want any new lines you can remove \n

```
dict[line[2]].append(line[3].replace("\n", ", "));
```

Here is the code

```
import csv;

dict={};
with open('training_data.csv','rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,skipinitialspace=True);
    for line in reader:
        try:
            dict[line[2]].append("\n"+line[3].replace("\n", ", "));
        except:
            dict[line[2]]=[line[3].replace("\n", ", ")];


with open('training_result.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',dialect='excel-tab');
    for key in dict:
        writer.writerow([key,','.join(dict[key])]);
```

Comment: What's with all the added semicolons?  Not required in Python.

Comment: I don't want to start a habit of not ending with semicolons(I am daily doing java and c#:) ) it is in blood now I prefer to keep it :) and no harm done by semicolons , at least for me .
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: That's not the Python style. See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  Public code should follow the expected style.

Comment: @ Mark Tolonen , It is simple. I dont care the style Since semicolons has no effect. I have 10 years history with java, c and c# and just got started with Python :) . They valid semicolon in python and I thanks Python builders for doing that.

Comment: You must really hate that Python doesn't use curly braces :)

Comment: Mark Tolonen , LOL YEAH!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the result you are looking for.  You didn't mention your Python version.  This is Python 3.  I used your sample data uploaded to Google Drive.  The file parsed as UTF-8.

Key things to note:

- `csv` has a `DictReader` to help select columns for processing.
- CSV files should be opened in binary mode.  In Python 2 that's just `'rb'` or `'wb'` but in Python 3 it means `'r',newline=''` and an encoding to the `open` call.
- `line` will be a dictionary of {'header':'value'} pairs.
- `extrasaction` tells `DictWriter` to ignore extra fields in the dictionary not listed in `fieldnames`.

Sample data:

```
twitter.place.full_name,twitter.user.location,interaction.author.username,interaction.content,interaction.created_at
"Gunungsari, Lombok Barat",Indonesia,__Thasya__,At Sheraton Senggigi Beach Resort äóî https://t.co/1FdTsMYWje,"Mon, 16 Jun 2014 15:32:54 +0000"
"Cakranegara, Kota Mataram",NULL,__Waone,Mataram,"Mon, 24 Mar 2014 13:13:46 +0000"
"Pemenang, Lombok Utara",Jakarta,_5at,"perdana, my first nephew from my lil sibling sister,,,

*moga gäó» ketularan songong kayak pamannya &gt;_&lt; http://t.co/UBEwcxWY5c","Sat, 04 Jan 2014 04:20:45 +0000"
"Pemenang, Lombok Utara",Jakarta,_5at,"@indiraputeri udah pinter bahasa sasak nih skrng,,, inaq rari","Sat, 04 Jan 2014 06:15:52 +0000"
"Pemenang, Lombok Utara",Jakarta,_5at,@indiraputeri dalemmm bgt nih ndoro .. !!! mksd nya apaan?,"Sat, 04 Jan 2014 05:55:04 +0000"
"Keruak, Lombok Timur",Jakarta,_5at,"pagi2, hujan, holiday, nasi goreng hangat, kopi hangat, di rumah, + spesial: kumpul keluarga,,, ^_^  *kurang_apa_lagi","Thu, 02 Jan 2014 00:02:47 +0000"
"Pujut, Lombok Tengah",Jakarta,_5at,"Doäó»a bepergian keluar rumah:

""Bismillaahitawakkaltu äó»alallooh""

*pasrah-pasrah-pasrah;
*bandara_international_lombok","Sun, 05 Jan 2014 03:36:48 +0000"
"Sakra, Lombok Timur",Jakarta,_5at,"Time for riding with my lil bro:
Mataram - Senggigi - Gili Terawangan
*jenguk_ponakan_baru;
*very_early","Fri, 03 Jan 2014 22:09:26 +0000"
"Sukamulia, Lombok Timur",,1821922,Salam friend,"Sun, 20 Jul 2014 19:23:53 +0000"
```

Code:

```
import csv

# Python 2 version of opens
#with open('training_data.csv','rb') as inp:
#    with open('training_result.csv','wb') as outp:

with open('training_data.csv','r',newline='',encoding='utf8') as inp:
    with open('training_result.csv','w',newline='',encoding='utf8') as outp:
        reader = csv.DictReader(inp)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outp,
                                fieldnames=['interaction.author.username','interaction.content'],
                                extrasaction='ignore')
        writer.writeheader()
        for line in reader:
            line['interaction.content'] = line['interaction.content'].replace('\n',' ')
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Result:

```
interaction.author.username,interaction.content
__Thasya__,At Sheraton Senggigi Beach Resort äóî https://t.co/1FdTsMYWje
__Waone,Mataram
_5at,"perdana, my first nephew from my lil sibling sister,,,  *moga gäó» ketularan songong kayak pamannya &gt;_&lt; http://t.co/UBEwcxWY5c"
_5at,"@indiraputeri udah pinter bahasa sasak nih skrng,,, inaq rari"
_5at,@indiraputeri dalemmm bgt nih ndoro .. !!! mksd nya apaan?
_5at,"pagi2, hujan, holiday, nasi goreng hangat, kopi hangat, di rumah, + spesial: kumpul keluarga,,, ^_^  *kurang_apa_lagi"
_5at,"Doäó»a bepergian keluar rumah:  ""Bismillaahitawakkaltu äó»alallooh""  *pasrah-pasrah-pasrah; *bandara_international_lombok"
_5at,Time for riding with my lil bro: Mataram - Senggigi - Gili Terawangan *jenguk_ponakan_baru; *very_early
1821922,Salam friend
```

Comment: @satya Uncomment the Python 2 version of the lines I posted in the code.